# IOS Archiving fails (React Native) while Debug working fine

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, archive

Im trying to archive an IOS build.

its working perfectly when running as debug build.

"react-natuve run-ios"

when i try to archive , Its throwing below error.

> Xcode/DerivedData/appname-crvjvqqnpdxpwkfkxccvnxunhhkw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname-app/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/appname.app/main.jsbundle
> does not exist. This must be a bug with'

please let me know how i can fix this..

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29351#issuecomment-657929014

Comment: In which file , we have to use/replace those 3 lines ?